# django haystack unable to remove stale records - AttributeError: Nonetype object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am using django-haystack 2.4.1 version with elasticsearch and django 1.8.11
I am having issues while updating the index with remove parameter. If some of my models get deleted and then if I run

```
./manage.py update_index --remove
```

I get the error **AttributeError: Nonetype object has no attribute '_meta'**

I checked the trace and found out that the error is coming from **default_get_identifier** method

```
default_get_identifier
    return u"%s.%s" % (get_model_ct(obj_or_string),
```

Here as the model is deleted already, get_model_ct returns the attribute error.

Then I found out about the **HAYSTACK_IDENTIFIER_METHOD** parameter, so I thought of defining my own method which is mentioned below

```
def getHaystackIdentifier(obj_or_string):
    return (str(obj_or_string)+"."+str(obj_or_string._get_pk_val()))
```

But the fundamental problem remains same as **obj_or_string** model is already deleted from the database,

How can I get the identifier of the stale records and delete them from index?

Shouldn't haystack automatically delete the records if model is not found corresponding to that? I am not sure if I am missing something here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue. The problem was HAYSTACK_ID_FIELD defined in django settings file as my field name (id) was colliding with the default haystack field. http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/settings.html#haystack-id-field

I changed my field name to something else and removed this setting and everything seems to be working fine. Note that even if I change my field name but don't remove this entry from settings file, it still gives me error.

Check the full trace of this error on github issues here
https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1380